# Filtering code coverage by calling function in OpenCover

Tags: code-coverage, opencover

I have some integration tests written for MsTest. The integration tests have the following structure:

```
[TestClass]
public class When_Doing_Some_Stuff
{
    [TestInitialize]
    protected override void TestInitialize()
    {
        // create the Integration Test Context
        EstablishContext();

        // trigger the Integration Test 
        When();
    }

    protected void EstablishContext()
    {
        // call services to set up context
    }

    protected override void When()
    {
        // call service method to be tested
    }

    [TestMethod]
    public void Then_Result_Is_Correct()
    {
        // assert against the result
    }
}
```

I need to filter the code coverage results of a function by who is calling it. Namely, I want the coverage to be considered only if the function is called from a function named "When" or which has a certain attribute applied to it.

Now, even if a certain method in the system is called in the EstablishContext part of some tests, the method is marked as visited.

I believe there is no filter for this and I would like to make the changes myself, as OpenCover is... well.. open. But I really have no idea where to start. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Have you decided to implement this feature then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be better addressing this with the OpenCover developers; hmmm... that would be me then, if you look on the [wiki](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/wiki) you will see that coverage by test is one of the eventual aims of OpenCover.

If you look at the [forking](https://github.com/sawilde/opencover/network) you will see a branch from mancau - he initially indicated that he was going to try to implement this feature but I do not know how far he has progressed or if he has abandoned his attempt (what he has submitted is just a small re-introduction of code to allow the tracing of calls).

OpenCover tracks by emitting a visit identifier and updating the next element in an array that resides in shared memory (shared between the profiler (C++/native/32-64bit) and the console (C#/managed/any-cpu)). What I suggested to him was (and this will be my approach when I get round to it, if no one else does and is why I emit the visit data in this way) that he may want to add markers into the sequence to indicate that he has entered/left a particular test method (filtered on [TestMethod] attribute perhaps) and then when processing the results in the console this can then be added to the model in some way. Threading may also be a concern as this could cause the interleaving of visit points for tests run in parallel.

Perhaps you will think of a different approach and I look forward to hearing your ideas.

Comment: This looks like what I wanted, but, sadly, I realized that it is beyond me, as I don't have enough experience with c++ to try to implement this myself.

Comment: No worries, I have started it myself, release3 currently supports nunit